# Python 3.5.3 and Oracle 11.2 on Windows 7: cannot locate oracle include files

Tags: python, oracle, windows-7, cx-oracle

I just installed `Python 3.5.3`, I also have an `Oracle Client` directory with a lot of `*.h` files in an `include` subdir...

but when I try a

`pip install cx_oracle`

I get:

```
distutils.errors.DistutilsSetupError: cannot locate Oracle include files in C:\oracle\instantclient_11_2
```

I am quite totally new to Python and I *really* would like to use it in web applications (it would be the first time we use Python at the firm I work) and I, definitely, need your help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using Oracle along with Python is a really headache. I've never got to make it work on Windows. I just switch to another DBMS :)

Comment: I really cannot swith to another DBMS :'(

Comment: Were you able to install cx_oracle with my solution ?

Comment: Hello Alex, thank you for your answer, I had to wait until my pc installed 240 (sic) windows updates...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to install dependencies from Oracle.

1. Download Installer from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winsoft-085727.html)
2. Add `ORACLE_HOME` as Windows environment variable and set the path of the unzipped folder e.g. `C:\....\Download\instantclient_12_1` as its value. Click [here](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) in case you don't know how to add environment variable.
3. Append this same path to the environment variable `Path`
4. `pip install cx_oracle`
5. Reboot your computer and start using cx_oracle!

Comment: Well, I set the path as you suggested then I downloaded the installer from Oracle, both the basic and the SDK, put everything in the same dir and got a "C++ is required" error. Went to http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools and then installed Build Tools 2015. Now I get the following:   
 85 unresolved externals
 error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\x86_amd64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120

Answer (score 4):

At the end of the day, thanks to Alex, I solved my problem.

What I did was:

1. Download from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html) both the `Instant Client Basics` for my `Windows 7` **64 bit** and the `Install Client SDK`.
2. Put everything in the same directory ( `C:\oracle\instantclient_12_1` )
3. Checked my system `path` and `ORACLE_HOME` variable. Check a variable with `echo %VARIABLE_NAME%` and then set it using [this procedure](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm). `ORACLE_HOME` must be set to `C:\oracle\instantclient_12_1` (in my case, yours could be different) and `PATH` must contain the same string.
4. Went to [here](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools) to download `Visual C++ Build Tools 2015`, as `C++` is required.
5. Eventually, did `pip install cx_oracle`

Make sure you have *everything* 32 or 64 bit: Install Client, Windows version, Python.

I run `Python 3.5.3`, I do not know if at the moment there is a `cx_oracle` that can be installed on `Python 3.6`.

Comment: What value do I need to give "echo %VARIABLE_NAME%" ?